# Install custom font in Azure Instance

Tags: c#, fonts, azure-web-roles, aurigma

How can i install custom fonts in an azure instance?

Using PrivateFontCollection is not an option as i'm using GraphicsMill API to render graphics, and it doesn't seem to support this feature, only fonts installed in system are allowed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the latest GM?

Graphics Mill 7 and higher supports drawing with custom fonts.

[Brief description.](http://www.graphicsmill.com/blog/2014/05/14/New-Drawing-API-in-Graphics-Mill-7)

[Samples.](https://github.com/aurigma/GraphicsMill.Samples/blob/master/D.FontAndText/D.02.FontLoadingAndTextMeasuring/FontLoadingAndTextMeasuringExample.cs)

Comment: Just for reference, in case anyone has the same situation ( where you have dynamic fronts and you cannot include them on the project ), as an instance is created every time the website is published all you have to do is on Application Startup download the Fonts from a repository to the website root, where you have full permission, and from there you can use the local path in PrivateFontCollection or in case of GraphicsMill, in the CustomFontRegistery.